# Is changing the default installation directories via the registry editor safe?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, windows-registry, regedit

I have recently purchased a small notebook (Trekstor Primebook), with only 32 GB of space on the `C:\` drive. Attached, is an M.2 SSD with ~256 GB  of storage that I would like to use as the default installation location for the majority of installed programs.

I have spent some time trying to figure out how to modify the location of the Windows installation directories (`Program Files(x86)` and `Program Files`) to be located on my attached SSD. Almost all I have found is telling me to modify the `ProgramFilesDir(x86)` and `ProgramFilesDir` values through `regedit` to the desired path, however, I am *extremely* wary of doing things like this.

Is this safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I don't recommend moving these sensitive folders, as you are taking a chance
with the stability of your system and even with its ability to boot.
It is much simpler to create folders with the same name on the D: drive,
then just manually specifying these folders whenever you are installing a new product.

If you intend to follow up with this, then before doing such a drastic change,
I suggest taking an image backup of the C: disk (do not store it on C:).
My recommended utility is
[AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.backup-utility.com/free-backup-software.html).
Create also its
[boot media](https://www.backup-utility.com/features/create-bootable-disc.html)
and test that it boots and can see the backup file.

The procedure is as follows for `Program Files` :

- Move the existing `C:\Program Files` folder to `D:\Program Files`.
  You might encounter permission problems that you will have to solve.
- Run as Administrator the Command Prompt (cmd)
- Enter inside the command : `CD \`
- Then the command :

  ```
  mklink /D "Program Files" "D:\Program Files"
  ```
- Done.